# Proof by induction with square root in denominator: $\frac1{2\sqrt1}+\frac1{3\sqrt2}+\dots+ \frac1{(n+1)\sqrt n} < 2-\frac2{\sqrt{(n+1)}}$

Tags: inequality, summation, induction

I need to prove $\frac{1}{2\sqrt1} + \frac{1}{3\sqrt2} + ... + \frac{1}{(n+1)\sqrt n} < 2 - \frac{2}{\sqrt{(n+1)}}$
by induction for every $n \in  \mathbb{N} $. 
Please help, I am stuck on this from the past 2 days..
Thanks.

Comment: Some past questions which seem related: [Proof of an inequality by induction: $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(k+1)\sqrt k}<2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/631810) and [If $ A=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1}}+\frac{1}{3\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{4\sqrt{3}}+.........+\frac{1}{100\sqrt{99}}\;,$ Then $\lfloor A \rfloor =$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1634645).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Great answer by [trancelocation](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/467003/trancelocation), but in case you still want it, here is how to do induction step for an inductive proof.  First we note the following general rule of quadratics:

$$(n + \tfrac{a+b}{2})^2 - (n+a)(n+b) = (\tfrac{a-b}{2})^2.$$

Using this rule with $a=1$ and $b=2$, we have:

$$(n+\tfrac{3}{2})^2 > (n+1)(n+2).$$

Rearranging this inequality gives:

$$\frac{(n+\tfrac{3}{2})^2}{n+1} > n+2.$$

Our inductive step can now be accomplished as follows:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{(k+1)\sqrt{k}} 
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(k+1)\sqrt{k}} + \frac{1}{(n+2)\sqrt{n+1}} \\[6pt]
&< 2 - \frac{2}{\sqrt{n+1}} + \frac{1}{(n+2)\sqrt{n+1}} \\[6pt]
&= 2 - \frac{2(n+2)-1}{(n+2)\sqrt{n+1}} \\[6pt]
&= 2 - \frac{2n+3}{(n+2)\sqrt{n+1}} \\[6pt]
&= 2 - \frac{2}{(n+2)} \cdot \frac{n+\tfrac{3}{2}}{\sqrt{n+1}} \\[6pt]
&< 2 - \frac{2}{(n+2)} \cdot \sqrt{n+2} \\[6pt]
&= 2 - \frac{2}{\sqrt{n+2}} . \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I think it is easier to just refer to the _AM_ mean inequality, that is: $$\begin{aligned}\frac{(n+1)+(n+2)}2>\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}&\iff n+\frac32>\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}\\&\iff\frac{n+\frac32}{\sqrt{n+1}}>\sqrt{n+2}\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 9):

Without induction you can show it immediately as follows:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}(k + 1)}\leq \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k \sqrt{k}} < \int_1^{n+1}\frac{1}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}\,dx =\left[-2\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \right]_1^{n+1} = 2 -\frac{2}{\sqrt{n+1}}$$

Comment: Thank you, but it is not with induction and I need it with.. For college..

Comment: @Gamenoob, popravni iz elementarne?  Smatraš li Benov odgovor korisnim, molim te, prihvati ga.

Comment: Sorry but from where did that integral came ? Can you please give a link to this technique ? I want to learn it.

Comment: @An_Elephant 
Check this out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence

Comment: Thanks very much sir :)